# Doing an action after promise.all finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, async-await

I have an array of promises and in the .then after the promise.all I am doing a lot of async functions, eventually what's improtent is that I am filling an array (eventually around 10,000 items will be in the array). I want to wait until the .then after the promise.all finishes so I can run  a for loop and add 100 out of the 10,000 items from the sorted array into a DB. How can I do that if I can't chain another .then after the .then after the promise.all?
Thanks

Comment: `if I can't chain a .then after promise.all?` Sure you can

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, editing now

Comment: Without seeing your code, it'll be quite difficult to figure out where you might be going wrong in your code

Comment: I have to disagree, the code is long and irrelevant. Inside the .then after the promise.all I am adding stuff to the DB + filling up an array. After the .then the array should be full, now I want to sort it, take out the top 100 and insert them into a DB.

Comment: The code is quite relevant - trim it down to a [MCVE] and post it in an edit to your question. Otherwise, there's no way to tell what's exactly's going on, and the question will likely be closed

Answer (score -1):

You can easily chain promises using multiple `then`

```
Promise.all([promise1, ...])
    .then(async () => {
        await something();
        await somethingElse();
    })
    .then(async () => {
        // your function to execute after everything
    });
```

Comment: I wasn't clear and edited my question. I am what I need inside the .then after the promise.all. I want to execute a function after this .then is finished